# Keyboard does not respond at POST screen, but works fine everywhere else?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, motherboard, post

```
Mobo: Gigabyte 7TESM
OS: Win 10 Pro
CPU: Dual Xeon X5650s
```

I’ve been dealing with this problem across two different motherboards. I understand it is an astronomically small possibility this happened back to back and am open to hear ideas.

At POST, I need to press F2 to enter BIOS. The system does not respond to keypresses. Once POST is over, PXE begins, followed by my onboard SAS initializing. Keypresses work fine at both of those screens. Enter Windows 10. Keyboard works without issues. What’s interesting to me is, when I’m pressing F2 at PPST, if I hold the button down, or press multiple buttons, the RAM counter spins slower or stops, so it’s recognizing keys are being pressed. If I press too many keys, it’ll beep after POST like I’ve pressed too many keys (I did ensure these weren’t warning beeps from my mobo, it only happens when I press a lot of keys)

Testing outside of the case worked without issue.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

- Three keyboards. Two USB, one PS/2.
- Making sure no other USB devices are plugged in.
- Tried each keyboard on each onboard and front panel USB port.
- Disconnecting the USB header and trying the onboard USB ports individually
- Resetting CMOS (on both boards more than once)
- Unplugging SSD with my OS on it (grasping straws here)
- Removing my graphics card.
- Inspected both CPU sockets for bent pins
- Ensured standoffs were tight and mounted correctly.

I keep hearing it might be a short - but can a short cause a specific problem at a specific screen that isn’t impacting any other function after that screen or process is over? Is it astronomically perfect timing that it only has an issue at POST?

Comment: Was it working before? How about other keys like F8 or DEL?

Comment: Yes, it worked before. On the 2nd mobo,

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too fast. On the 2nd mobo, it worked for a few weeks then suddenly stopped. On the third mobo, it worked outside of the case and immediately went into the case and stopped working at POST only.

Comment: When you boot without disks, does it go into the BIOS?

Comment: No. Same error. The first time I bench tested didn’t have disks and it worked. But the bench test after removing the mobo again did not work

Answer (score 0):

If post fails to recognise your USB keyboard and your USB connection is known to be good then try a PS2 keyboard till you can get into windows to load the correct keyboard driver.
Also try another USB port to eliminate that possibility and test the keyboard in another system.
Also ensure your Bios is up to date.

Comment: Already stated I’ve tried ps/2. Correct drivers have been installed prior.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to switch on "USB legacy" mode or something like that in the bios. (Use a ps/2-keyboard for this).

Sometimes it is called "usb during boot" or so.

PS/2-keyboards often need to be plugged in before switching the pc on. Did you try that?

Do you have UEFI boot enabled? Then you could force the pc to boot into bios from your operating system.

Comment: How can I possibly enter BIOS and change a setting if I’m unable to enter BIOS at POST? That is the exact problem I’m writing about. Also, that support is turned on by default with this board, when I was able to get in the first time, i made sure it was.

Comment: Do not have UEFI as an option - it’s an older board. Is it something I can turn on within Windows 10 for any board?